# MEAN Stack AngularJS Error - Argument 'AppControl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't understand where's the problem, I new to MEAN.

[image: HTML CODE]

And the Controller:

```
function AppControl($scope){
  console.log("Hello World from controller");
  person1 = {
    name: 'Maruf',
    email: 'mhtamun@gmail.com',
    phone: '01671010143'
  };
  person2 = {
    name: 'Afif',
    email: 'sam@yahoo.com',
    phone: '0123456789'
  };
  var contactlist = [person1, person2];
  scope.contactlist = contactlist;
}
```

What I am doing wrong? 
Error: ng:areq
Bad Argument - 
Argument 'AppControl' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: Can you post the full code of the `controller.js`?

Comment: Don't add images of your code, simply paste it in here. It's better.

Comment: @ShaohaoLin This is full controller, I am just learning.

Comment: @phiterFernandes Stackoverflow create difficulties to add code ...

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can just Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V. The select the code and click in the `{  }` icon on top of the question textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using controller you need to define angular module:

```
angular.module('controllerAsExample', [/*Some dependencies*/])
```

And then define controllers.

```
angular.module('controllerAsExample').controller('SomeController', functionName);
```

Then provide function for controller:

```
function functionName($scope, $rootScope, etc){
   ...some code..
}
```

Here is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CvJc6oBKeyTao4WqSZvF?p=preview) with example;

Comment: Argument 'AppControl' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: can you post code of html-page? I'll give you a working plunker

Comment: Here is working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CvJc6oBKeyTao4WqSZvF?p=preview)   Also you have a typo in `scope` it must be `$scope`

Comment: For another function what I have to do?

Comment: complemented answer. The main idea is in `angular.module('controllerAsExample').controller('SomeController', functionName);`